# MATLAB - persistent variable

Tags: matlab, variables, persistent

How to retain the value of a persistent variable in MATLAB after clearing it from memory?

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`mlock`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/mlock.html) to prevent clearing of a function from memory until Matlab quits. This will also prevent all the [`persistent`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/persistent.html) variables that were defined in within this function from clearing, as it is stated in the documentation:

> mlock locks the currently running function in memory so that
>   subsequent clear functions do not remove it. Locking a function in
>   memory **also prevents any persistent variables defined in the file from
>   getting reinitialized**.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking is a contradiction, either the variable retains it value or you clear it? You can't have both. Maybe you want to put the value in a separate temporary variable? Otherwise have a look at [clearvars](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clearvars.html) with the `-except` tag or otherwise for the `save` function. Type `help save` in the command line to learn how to store a variables for use at a later stage.